# url rewriting not working on my server

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am having some problems with my url rewriting in my .htaccess. They work well locally but for some reason i don't understand, they don't work on my server. I was able to make my first rule work by adding a question mark after the index.php like so (i also don't understand why it needs this question mark) :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index\.php?/$1 [L]
```

But i still cannot find a way to make this rule work on my server.

```
RewriteRule article/([a-zA-z0-9\-]+)-([0-9]+)/ article/$1/$2/ [L]
```

Could you tell me what am i doing wrong and why it works locally but not on my server ? Thanks !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed work this out. I looked at the $_SERVER variable on my server and found out that the rewritten url was stored in the $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']. Don't ask me why ...

So i am using this variable instead of $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] and every things works perfectly again.
URLS like this : /article/lala-00000000164/ are invisibly rewritten as so : /article/lala/00000000164/.

Thanks for the help !!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you need the question mark because your server isn't setup to handle PATH_INFO. But you need the article rule *before* your other rule:

```
RewriteRule article/([a-zA-z0-9\-]+)-([0-9]+)/ article/$1/$2/ [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index\.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks, i tried that already and i get /article/lala/00000000164/ was not found on this server. So i tried : article/([a-zA-z0-9\-]+)-([0-9]+)/ index.php?/article/$1/$2/ [L]. Now i am redirected to index.php but the rewriting isn't working. The $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] says that the url is /article/lala-00000000164/ instead of /article/lala/00000000164/

Comment: @user2588917 Do you want it to redirect the browser or something? Because the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` is going to be what the browser requests and **not** what mod_rewrite changes it to.

Comment: Hi yes i think i understand where i am going wrong. I was using $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] locally. But this variable is not set on my server. So i replaced it with $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] and that is where the problem comes from. With $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'], a url like this : /article/lala-00000000164/ is transformed to /article/lala/00000000164/ so i can parse it easily. But the url in $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] is not transformed... Is there anyway i can get this to work the way i like ?

Comment: @user2588917 because of the `?` in your rule's target, you need to be looking at `$_GET` array.